# Error message when attempting to define a function

Tags: python, function

Using python on repl.it

Attempting to define a function, and getting a vague syntax error when trying to run the program. I have attempted to fix this by redoing the indentations, with no luck. Please help. code below

```
health = 10

def labencounter():
  entity = 'alchemist'
  battlevar = 0
  entityhp = 10
  print('An alchemist jumps out of the darkness, surrounded by neon ooze and bubbling vats!')
  battleaction = str(input('What will you do? [a]ttack [s]uper attack [i]tem or [r]un?'))
  while entityhp > 0:
    while battlevar  < 0:
      if battleaction == 'a':
        battlevar += 1
        entityhp -= 1
        health -= 3
        print('The ' + entity + '\'s health is' + entityhealth + '! Your health is ' + health)
        battlevar = 0
      elif battleaction == 's':
        battlevar += 1
        entityhp -= 3
        health -= 2
        print('The ' + entity + '\'s health is' + entityhealth + '! Your health is ' + health)
        battlevar = 0
      elif battleaction == 'i':
        battlevar += 1
        print('You have no items!')
        battlevar = 0
      elif battleaction == 'r':
        print('It chases you down and kills you.')
        health -= 10
      else:
        battleaction = str(input('[a]ttack [s]uper attack [i]tem or [r]un')


def entryway():
  x = 0
  enter = input('You see a gigantic doorway, yawning in the morning sun. Will you forsake the light and enter the dungeon? [y]/[n]')
  while x < 1:
    if enter.lower() != 'y' and enter != 'n':
      enter = input('[y]/[n]')
    elif enter.lower() == 'y':
      x += 1
      print('The darkness grows around you, as you yourself do the same into the abyss.')
    else:
      print('You turn away. Caves are not meant for one such as you.')
      exit()
```

with an error message reading

```
  File "main.py", line 34
    def entryway():
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The problem is in a part of the code that you didn't show. Probably, you forgot to close parentheses on the line before...

Comment: The error probably lies on what is before the function. Can be identation, parenthesis or some unclosed loop or something. Please edit and add what is before, up to line 34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't closed the brackets on line 31

`battleaction = str(input('[a]ttack [s]uper attack [i]tem or [r]un')`